# How to override iOS System Vibration Settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-vibrate

I've just recently noticed that they're are two switches inside the Settings Application that say "Vibrate on Ring" and "Vibrate on Silent". If these switches are turned to OFF, I am not able to vibrate the phone from my application.

I currently call vibrate using:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound( kSystemSoundID_Vibrate );
```

The question is: Does anyone know how to override these settings and vibrate the phone no matter what the settings are?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change user settings for the core functionality of the phone. You build on top of the OS, not really in it. All the things we can do are because Apple created APIs to let us do so. If there was some crazy hack to get around that using undocumented APIs Apple would reject the app anyway. Happened to me once under a different circumstance over something super minor that I didn't know was "undocumented."